# ROUNDING OFF with the numbers to upper value usind sheets formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am expecting the result after rounding for 161.24 to be 161.5 and if the value is 161.75 then it must be rounded to 162, if it is 161.68 then it must be rounded to 162

I have used `=MROUND(value, "0.5")` but I dont get the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you expected, you should use:

```
=CEILING.MATH(value,0.5)
```

Comment: Even just `CEILING(value,0.5)` should still be supported.